# SQL Server: stored procedure not adding any data without any error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two table master & detail. I am passing a xml to a stored procedure as parameter value, but when my stored procedure code executes, no data is getting inserted and no error is thrown. I am not able to understand where the problem lies.

Can anyone help me to get the wrong area in my stored procedure code which causes the problem?

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE TblTickerTemplate 
(
    ID INT IDENTITY,
    Ticker VARCHAR(20),
    LineItem VARCHAR(100),
    Insertdate DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE()

    CONSTRAINT PK_ID PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ID)
);

ALTER Table TblTickerTemplate
    ADD CONSTRAINT UC_Ticker_LineItem UNIQUE (Ticker, LineItem)

CREATE TABLE TblTickerTemplateDetail 
(
    MasterTemplateID INT,
    ID INT IDENTITY,
    LineItem VARCHAR(100),
    XFundCode VARCHAR(100),
    Action CHAR(1),
    UserID VARCHAR(20),
    Insertdate DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE()

    FOREIGN KEY(MasterTemplateID) REFERENCES TblTickerTemplate(ID)
);
```

Procedure code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE USP_InsertUniqueLineItems
    (@INPUTXML xml,
     @STATUS VARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT)
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    BEGIN TRANSACTION   
    BEGIN TRY  
        DECLARE @TblTickerTemplateDetailID AS INT 
        DECLARE @XMLFormat AS INT
        DECLARE @Ticker AS VARCHAR(MAX)
        DECLARE @ID AS INT
        DECLARE @Lineitem AS VARCHAR(MAX)
        DECLARE @XFundCode AS VARCHAR(MAX)
        DECLARE @UserID AS VARCHAR(MAX)

        --load xml data into cursor
        EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @XMLFormat OUTPUT, @INPUTXML

        DECLARE CURRECORD CURSOR LOCAL FOR
            SELECT Ticker, ID, Lineitem, XFundCode, @UserID
            FROM OPENXML (@XMLFORMAT, '/Lineitems', 1)
                WITH (
                    Ticker    VARCHAR(MAX),
                    ID        INT,
                    Lineitem  VARCHAR(MAX),
                    XFundCode VARCHAR(MAX),
                    UserID    VARCHAR(MAX)
                 )


        SET @TblTickerTemplateDetailID = 0

        -- open cursor
        OPEN CURRECORD
        FETCH NEXT FROM CURRECORD INTO @Ticker,@ID,@Lineitem,@XFundCode,@UserID

        -- iterate in cursor to fetch value
        WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS=0)
        BEGIN

            -- if ID == 0 then new data it will be inserted in TblTickerTemplate & TblTickerTemplateDetail table
            IF @ID = 0
            BEGIN
                IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT LineItem  FROM TblTickerTemplate WHERE LineItem = @Lineitem AND Ticker = @Ticker)
                BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO TblTickerTemplate(Ticker,LineItem)
                        VALUES (@Ticker,@Lineitem)

                    SET @TblTickerTemplateDetailID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

                    INSERT INTO TblTickerTemplateDetail (MasterTemplateID,LineItem,XFundCode,UserID,[Action])
                        VALUES (@TblTickerTemplateDetailID,@Lineitem,@XFundCode,@UserID,'I')                    
                END
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                    -- if ID > 0 means existing data & the data will be inserted in TblTickerTemplateDetail table only

                    INSERT INTO TblTickerTemplateDetail (MasterTemplateID,LineItem,XFundCode,UserID,[Action])
                        VALUES (@ID,@Lineitem,@XFundCode,@UserID,'U')
            END

        FETCH NEXT FROM CURRECORD INTO @Ticker,@ID,@Lineitem,@XFundCode,@UserID
        END

        IF @ID = 0
        BEGIN                       
            SET @STATUS='New Line items successfully inserted' 
        END
        ELSE IF @ID > 0
        BEGIN     
            SET @STATUS='Existing Line items successfully updated' 
        END

        CLOSE CURRECORD
        DEALLOCATE CURRECORD    
        COMMIT TRANSACTION



    END TRY  

    BEGIN CATCH  

        DECLARE @ERROR INT, @MESSAGE VARCHAR(4000)
        SELECT @ERROR = ERROR_NUMBER(),@MESSAGE = ERROR_MESSAGE()   

        --SET @STATUS='Line items insert fail' 
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION 

        RAISERROR ('USP_InsertUniqueLineItems:', 16, 1, @ERROR, @MESSAGE) 
        --SET @STATUS='Fail-- '+@MESSAGE
        --RETURN

    END CATCH;

    SET NOCOUNT OFF
END

Calling procedure this way
--------------------------

Declare @inputxml xml  
Declare @Status VARCHAR(MAX)

 set @inputxml='<Lineitems>
  <Lineitem>
    <Ticker>TER</Ticker>
    <ID>0</ID>
    <LineItem>Net Revenue</LineItem>
    <XFundCode>TRIN</XFundCode>
    <UserID>TDP</UserID>
  </Lineitem>
  <Lineitem>
    <Ticker>TER</Ticker>
    <ID>0</ID>
    <LineItem>Cost of Revenue</LineItem>
    <XFundCode>XXP</XFundCode>
    <UserID>TDP</UserID>    
  </Lineitem>
</Lineitems>'

 EXEC [dbo].USP_InsertUniqueLineItems @inputxml, @Status output

 Select @Status
```

### Edit

I solved this way

```
/*
SAMPLE XML to insert
<Lineitems>
  <Lineitem>
    <Ticker>TER</Ticker>
    <ID>0</ID>
    <LineItem>Net Revenue</LineItem>
    <XFundCode>TRIN</XFundCode>
    <UserID>TDP</UserID>
  </Lineitem>
  <Lineitem>
    <Ticker>TER</Ticker>
    <ID>0</ID>
    <LineItem>Cost of Revenue</LineItem>
    <XFundCode>XXP</XFundCode>
    <UserID>TDP</UserID>    
  </Lineitem>
</Lineitems>
*/

ALTER Procedure USP_InsertUniqueLineItems
(
    @INPUTXML xml,
    @STATUS VARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT  
)

AS 

BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    BEGIN TRANSACTION   
    BEGIN TRY  
        Declare @TblTickerTemplateDetailID  AS INT 

        Declare @XMLFormat                  AS INT

        Declare @Ticker                     AS VARCHAR(MAX)
        Declare @ID                         AS INT
        Declare @Lineitem                   AS VARCHAR(MAX)
        Declare @XFundCode                  AS VARCHAR(MAX)
        Declare @UserID                     AS VARCHAR(MAX)

        --load xml data into cursor
        Exec sp_xml_preparedocument @XMLFormat OUTPUT, @INPUTXML

        DECLARE CURRECORD
        CURSOR LOCAL FOR
        SELECT ID,Ticker,LineItem,XFundCode,UserID
        FROM OPENXML (@XMLFORMAT, '/Lineitems/Lineitem', 2)
        WITH (
            ID                      INT,
            Ticker                  VARCHAR(MAX),
            LineItem                VARCHAR(MAX),
            XFundCode               VARCHAR(MAX),
            UserID                  VARCHAR(MAX)
         )


        SET @TblTickerTemplateDetailID = 0

        -- open cursor
        OPEN CURRECORD
        FETCH NEXT FROM CURRECORD INTO @ID,@Ticker,@Lineitem,@XFundCode,@UserID

        -- iterate in cursor to fetch value
        WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS=0)
        BEGIN

            -- if ID == 0 then new data it will be inserted in TblTickerTemplate & TblTickerTemplateDetail table
            IF @ID = 0
            BEGIN
                IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT *  FROM TblTickerTemplate WHERE LineItem = @Lineitem AND Ticker = @Ticker)
                BEGIN
                    Print @Ticker+' '+@Lineitem

                    INSERT INTO TblTickerTemplate(Ticker,LineItem)
                        VALUES (@Ticker,@Lineitem)

                    SET @TblTickerTemplateDetailID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
                    SET @STATUS='New Line items successfully inserted' 

                    INSERT INTO TblTickerTemplateDetail (MasterTemplateID,LineItem,XFundCode,UserID,[Action])
                        VALUES (@TblTickerTemplateDetailID,@Lineitem,@XFundCode,@UserID,'I')                    
                END
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                    -- if ID > 0 means existing data & the data will be inserted in TblTickerTemplateDetail table only

                    INSERT INTO TblTickerTemplateDetail (MasterTemplateID,LineItem,XFundCode,UserID,[Action])
                        VALUES (@ID,@Lineitem,@XFundCode,@UserID,'U')
            END

        FETCH NEXT FROM CURRECORD INTO @ID,@Ticker,@Lineitem,@XFundCode,@UserID
        END

        -- storing message to OUTPUT type variable
        IF @ID = 0
        BEGIN                       
            SET @STATUS='New Line items successfully inserted' 
        END
        ELSE IF @ID > 0
        BEGIN     
            SET @STATUS='Existing Line items successfully updated' 
        END

        CLOSE CURRECORD
        DEALLOCATE CURRECORD    
        COMMIT TRANSACTION

    END TRY  

    BEGIN CATCH  

        -- Error handling part
        DECLARE @ERROR INT, @MESSAGE VARCHAR(4000)
        SELECT @ERROR = ERROR_NUMBER(),@MESSAGE = ERROR_MESSAGE()   

        SET @STATUS='Fail-- '+@MESSAGE      
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION 

        --RAISERROR ('USP_InsertUniqueLineItems:', 16, 1, @ERROR, @MESSAGE) 
        RETURN

    END CATCH;

    SET NOCOUNT OFF
END
```

but if I uncomment this line

```
RAISERROR ('USP_InsertUniqueLineItems:', 16, 1, @ERROR, @MESSAGE)
```

then error is thrown. How to fix it? Share some ideas. Thanks

Comment: Out of interest, why are you using a `CURSOR` here? Why not just insert the whole lot in one go and use an `OUTPUT` clause?

Comment: Don't use `sp_xml_preparedocument`/`OPENXML`; these are inferior in performance and ease of use to the `XML` type and its methods (`.nodes()`, `.value()`) (and a resource leak if you forget to call `sp_xml_removedocument`, as you have). And, per Larnu, get rid of the `CURSOR`; you can use two passes over the document, one to insert all `tblTickerTemplate` and capture their IDs and one to insert all `tblTickerTemplateDetail`s.

Comment: provide some code example if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Stored procedure not adding any data without any error*

It is because the OPENXML simply returns NULL.

```
SELECT 
    Ticker, ID, Lineitem, XFundCode, @UserID
FROM 
    OPENXML (@XMLFORMAT, '/Lineitems', 1)
        WITH (
            Ticker                  VARCHAR(MAX),
            ID                      INT,
            Lineitem                VARCHAR(MAX),
            XFundCode               VARCHAR(MAX),
            UserID                  VARCHAR(MAX)
         );
```

should be:

```
SELECT 
    Ticker, ID, Lineitem, XFundCode, @UserID
FROM 
    OPENXML (@XMLFORMAT, '/Lineitems/Lineitem', 2)
    WITH (
        Ticker                  VARCHAR(MAX),
        ID                      INT,
        Lineitem                VARCHAR(MAX),
        XFundCode               VARCHAR(MAX),
        UserID                  VARCHAR(MAX)
     )
```

Please note change from **1 (attribute centric)** to **2 (element centric)** mode of OPENXML and change of `'/Lineitems'` to `'/Lineitems/Lineitem'`.

Also:

```
Exec sp_xml_preparedocument
```

should have corresponding

```
EXEC sp_xml_removedocument
```

To sum up: I agree with comment that you should avoid `sp_xml_preparedocument/OPENXML/CURSOR` and rewrite it entirely by using `.value/nodes` syntax.

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e956cf9302f4fcf799652963d86dc30d)**

Comment: thanks a lot. but getting error for this line `RAISERROR ('USP_InsertUniqueLineItems:', 16, 1, @ERROR, @MESSAGE) `  error message is `Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure dbo.USP_InsertUniqueLineItems, Line 119
USP_InsertUniqueLineItems:`

Comment: again i am getting this error `Fail-- Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UC_Ticker_LineItem'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.TblTickerTemplate'. The duplicate key value is (TER, <NULL>).` but my Ticker & Lineitem is composite unique key. in xml ticker & lineitem is ok then why getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

hi try this code for while inserting.

```
Declare @inputxml xml  


 set @inputxml='<Lineitems>
  <Lineitem>
    <Ticker>TER</Ticker>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <LineItem>Net Revenue</LineItem>
    <XFundCode>TRIN</XFundCode>
    <UserID>TDP</UserID>
  </Lineitem>
  <Lineitem>
    <Ticker>TER</Ticker>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <LineItem>Cost of Revenue</LineItem>
    <XFundCode>XXP</XFundCode>
    <UserID>TDP</UserID>    
  </Lineitem>
</Lineitems>'


        SELECT

      T.C.value('(ID)[1]', 'int')

      ,T.C.value('(Ticker)[1]', 'varchar(max)')

      ,T.C.value('(LineItem)[1]', 'varchar(max)')

      ,T.C.value('(XFundCode)[1]', 'varchar(max)')
      ,T.C.value('(UserID)[1]', 'varchar(max)')


   FROM @inputxml.nodes('Lineitems/Lineitem') T(C)
```

please change variable data type according to your requirement in select statement or it will be you error for that.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has numerous issues, more than I care to count. It really looks like it was ported from SQL Server 2000 database with some minimal additions, such as `try / catch` block and `max` data types.

Essentially, your entire `TRY` can be replaced with these 2 statements:

```
insert into dbo.TblTickerTemplate (LineItem, Ticker)
select t.c.value('(./LineItem/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
  t.c.value('(./Ticker/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)')
from @inputxml.nodes('./Lineitems[1]/Lineitem[(./ID/text())[1] = "0"]') t(c);

insert into dbo.TblTickerTemplateDetail ([Action], LineItem, MasterTemplateID, UserID, XFundCode)
select case t.c.value('(./ID/text())[1]', 'int') when 0 then 'I' else 'U' end as [Action],
  t.c.value('(./LineItem/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') as [LineItem],
  m.ID as [MasterTemplateId],
  t.c.value('(./UserID/text())[1]', 'varchar(20)') as [UserId],
  t.c.value('(./XFundCode/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') as [XFundCode]
from dbo.TblTickerTemplate m
  inner join @inputxml.nodes('./Lineitems[1]/Lineitem') t(c) on
    m.LineItem = t.c.value('(./LineItem/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)')
    and m.Ticker = t.c.value('(./Ticker/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)');
```

It's not particularly optimal - for decently sized XML (100+ nodes) it's usually better to cache the data in the relational form first, either in a @table variable (they already existed in 2000, yes) or #temporary table. Also, in the first insert you would want to add the existence check, so that newly inserted rows would not break your natural key. But as a skeleton it will suffice, yes.

Another thing I've noticed is that the `./UserID` attribute is actually never used - your code puts the `@UserID` variable into the cursor declaration, and then the variable (which is `NULL` at this point) is assigned to itself in the `fetch next`. A typo or a copy-paste, no doubt.

Comment: is it possible to insert data one after one using xquery ?

Comment: @T_Zacks, you mean, cursor style? Yes, but it's hugely inefficient, just like any other looped inserts, for that matter. Why you would possibly need that? Is there some logic that you can't include into the `select` that provides the data?

Comment: using xquery how could loop into data and insert into table one by one. is it possible ?

Comment: tell me why [1] is mention `t.c.value('(./LineItem/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)')` what is the meaning of [1] ? it could be [0] or [2] but you used [1] please mention the reason?

Comment: Number in square brackets designates the ordinal position of the element to retrieve (1-based, so it can't be zero). Inside the `value()`, however, it's essentially mandatory because otherwise SQL Server will think you are trying to return a set from a scalar method.